# Java + Google Web Toolkit (google apps engine) download file from server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I have deployed an application in Google App Engine and and I want to upload and download data from server using java code at desktop and server code for download request and one more: Where do I store  the data in apps engine?

Comment: hey i am making application which on user request send them a latest file ,i,e get download to user end and where should i store that file and how i direct it as output stream

Comment: Do u have any servlet serving the files?

Comment: suppose if i do have servlet then where esle i store my file and data as apps engine now provide cloud storage on pricing basis i m in need for free hosting server where can i test and deploy my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store binary data (file contents) you have three options:

1. [Blob property of Datastore entities](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Properties_and_Value_Types)
2. [Blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/)
3. [Google Cloud Storage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/)

Comment: can i get any free hosting server where i can test my application ,, that do have all space and java capabilities i dont want to test on local host

Comment: App engine is free up to a certain limit: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas

Answer (score 0):

You can save your file anywhere on your server, you just need to know the path.

> how i direct it as output stream?

Here is a code snippet that can help you.

```
File fileOnServer = new File("Hello.txt"); // Give full path where your file is located

byte[] file = new byte[(int) fileOnServer.length()];

FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileOnServer);
fileInputStream.read(file);

int contentLength = (int) file.length;
response.setContentLength(contentLength);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Hello.txt\"");
out = response.getOutputStream();


int bytesWritten = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
while (bytesWritten < contentLength) {
    int bytes = Math.min(1024, contentLength - bytesWritten);
    System.arraycopy(file, bytesWritten, buffer, 0, bytes);
    if (bytes > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
        bytesWritten += bytes;
    } else if (bytes < 0);
}
```

> get download to user end?

Well you can add ClickHandler on a Button on your client side and override `onClick` method.

```
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        Window.open("UrlToYourServelet", "_blank", "null");
}
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

I have found a solution. You can upload the file at any free file hosting site like [this](http://www.4shared.com/). This site provides a URL for every uploaded file. So in your servelet, make a HTTP request to the URL and download the file in `byte[]` and write it on outputStream as shown in the code above.

Comment: i guess you wrote the right answer but i am not owning any server i am using google apps enginee for apps deployment .. see this is the sample apps http://smereseda.appspot.com/ but i dont have any storage there so i am thinking that i might get some free space like dropbox where i can place my data and forward user to that but in case of dropox i have to make my data public that i dont let user to access

Comment: and if i use your above code as apps engine do support servlet and war file but where do i place the file as it does not provide free space //Give full path where your file is located

Comment: why dont u use BlobStore? Its free i guess. You can simply store your file in `byte[]` and access it through Blobstore. 

Have a look at this link. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview

Comment: BlobStore is not free. Sorry. But try Datastore APi its free. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/

Comment: this link might be helpful. http://clockfly.deepant.com/2011/07/use-google-app-engine-to-setup.html